# Segmentation fault in openssl_sign under apache, but allright in CLI

Tags: php, openssl, segmentation-fault

I have PHP code that signs request using openssl_sign:

```
if (($pkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_private($keystr)) === false)
{
  $this->setError('Cannot retrieve private key from: ' . $this->getParam('keyFile'));
  return false;
}
if (!openssl_sign($message, $sign, $pkeyid, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1))
{
  $this->setError('Cannot sign with private key');
  return false;
}
```

It is working normally when code is run in CLI, but under Apache (php 5.2.17 as module) line with `!openssl_sign($message, $sign, $pkeyid, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1)` results in segfault (11).

`$pkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_private($keystr)` gives valid key.

Have someone encountered such error? What is solution if any? Alternatives compliant with openssl_sign? How it could be rapidly diagnosed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause: both your PHP module and the apache `httpd` itself are linked against `libopenssl`, but different versions of it, causing symbols from the "wrong" library to get called.

Set `ulimit -c unlimited`, let `httpd` dump `core`, and analyse it with `gdb`:

```
gdb /path/to/httpd /path/to/core
(gdb) info shared
# look for more than one instance of openssl

(gdb) info func EVP_SignFinal
# look for more than one definition -- one could be statically linked into httpd
```

Comment: Thanks. One question only - how I make httpd to dump core?

Comment: I decided just to recompile httpd, anyway, thanks for idea about different versions of lib in httpd and php.